# Need to Identify Img Tag by coordinates

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, image, coordinates

I need to change the color of any image that contains a particular x coordinate. However, the code I am using now only gives me the #scrollwrapper container, and not the individual image that is at that location.

```
var xHome = window.innerWidth/2;
        var yHome = window.innerHeight/2;
        var pElement = document.elementFromPoint(xHome, yHome);
        alert (pElement.className);
```

This gets wrapper container on the images, but not the particular image that is there. The site is coolaidhouse.com/projectcaptured

You can see the scroller there. I want to dim the images on the side of the "active," item, which is basically the image closest to the middle.

If I could get the image based on its coordinates I could do the rest. However, I can't figure out how to get the image in lieu of the container.

Here is what the end result should look like:
[image: Notice middle image is active looking]

Comment: How can I mark this as the answer?

Comment: My comment was a suggestion, but I've now posted it as an answer since it solved your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Your code grabs the image when run from the console. Therefore, you need to wait for the image to load before running the code.

IMG elements have an `onload` event you can use for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was in Rick Hitchcock's comment. Don't know how to mark a comment as an answer though. The images were in fact not loaded yet.